# Function to find the least prime factor

Tags: factorization, pari, pari-gp

Does PARI/GP have a function for finding the smallest prime factor of a `t_INT` or otherwise perform a partial factorization of an integer?

For example, if I have the number:

```
a=261432792226751124747858820445742044652814631500046047326053169701039080900441047539208779404889565067
```

it takes a long time to do `factor(a)` because `a` contains two huge prime factors. However, it is quite easy to find that `17` is a divisor of `a`.

Of course in this case I could have used just `forprime(p=2,,a % p == 0 && return(p))` or a similar trial division to find the factor. But if the least factor had had 20 decimal figures, say, that would be impractical, and I might have wanted to use the sophisticated methods of `factor` in that case.

So it would be ideal if I could call `factor` with some kind of flag saying I will be happy with any partial factorization, or saying that all I care about is the smallest non-trivial divisor, etc.

Comment: Have you thought about a variant of the [Lenstra elliptic-curve factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization) (which specializes in getting small factors)?  You could modify it to break once it has found any factor.

Comment: @JosephWood PARI's `factor` or `factorint` function already uses elliptic-curve methods as one of its approaches. I know I could code my own elliptic curve implementation, but I was asking if there was something built-in in PARI/GP.

Comment: The PARI library has the function `Z_factor_until` which might be useful. But proving that you've found the smallest prime factor isn't generally easy, choose one option: works only on special numbers, some only 'with high probability' rather than certainty; long running time; works only on small numbers.

Comment: Also, for numbers larger than 40 digits, you're much better off with [yafu](https://sourceforge.net/projects/yafu/).

Answer (score 1):

A very simple partial answer to my question is that `factor` has an optional argument `lim`, so you can just say:

```
factor(a, 10^5)
```

for example, and only factors below `10^5` will appear in the result (the cofactor greater than `10^5` can be composite!).

The optional argument to `factorint` is entirely different, a bit-wise "flag", and it does not allow to specify a limit. That was probably what confused me. As an example:

```
factorint(a, 1+8)
```

*selects* flags `1` ("avoid MPQS") and `8` ("don't run final ECM").